# Connection error from AWS EC2 node to a Oralce Database in Datacenter

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jboss, database-connection

I am trying to connect to a Oracle Database from a Java Webapplication hosted on a AWS environment.
I have opened up the Firewall to the Database server via the port 1521.
Still getting the error when i ping the DB server from the AWS node.
The Oracle DB is located within our datacenter.

Is there any other configuration that needs to be done AWS or any other firewall configurations to be done.

Ping error:

```
[root@ip-AWS-Node ~]# ping -a Database-sever-IP
PING Database-sever-IP (Database-sever-IP) 56(84) bytes of data.
--- Database-sever-IP ping statistics ---
19 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 18597ms
```

Jboss Error log:

```
INFO  [stdout] (http-/ip-AWS-Node:8080-1) Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
INFO  [stdout] (http-/ip-AWS-Node:8080-1)       at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:288)
INFO  [stdout] (http-/ip-AWS-Node:8080-1)       at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:246)
INFO  [stdout] (http-/ip-AWS-Node:8080-1)       at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:781)
INFO  [stdout] (http-/ip-AWS-Node:8080-1)       at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:344)
INFO  [stdout] (http-/ip-AWS-Node:8080-1)       ... 52 more
INFO  [stdout] (http-/ip-AWS-Node:8080-1) Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

Comment: Might I suggest you ask this question on http://serverfault.com/?  Stack Overflow is specifically for programming questions.  This is more sysadmin-related.

Comment: Are you connecting over public ip or you have direct connection setup and connecting over private ip? Does your instance is inside VPC? If yes does your subnet has an instance gateway attached to this? Can you reach any other hosts from that instance?